# <mat-icon> doesn't look like expected

Tags: html, angular

I want to use a `<mat-icon>` so I looked it up and i found this:

```
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" aria-label="Example icon button with a home icon">
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
</button>
```

(https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples)

but the problem is it looks like this:
[image]

and it should look like this:
[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: Hi, is the animation missing or what exactly?

Comment: Yeah the animation and the elevation(i think it is called like that) is missing

Comment: <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon">home</mat-icon>
for more details please visit official site https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview for more explanation. Have a great Day !!

Comment: I see in the [getting started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) section of angular material that you have to add some `BrowserAnimationsModule`. Do you have that? Have you followed these steps exactly?

Comment: Thanks `ng add @angular/material` was the solution

Comment: Glad it worked, cheers!